# GORM add foreign key value to already exist object

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I use MySQL db and working with grails. I created 2 tables and I have a column which presents a foreign key between the tables (I used hasMany).
This is what I have in general:

```
class Address {

  static belongsTo = Person
  static mapping = {
    street defaultValue: "'s'"
    city defaultValue: "'c'"
 }
}
```

and

```
class Person {
  private String firstName
  private String lastName

  Set<Address> addresses;
  static hasMany = [addresses: Address]

  static mapping = {
    table 'people'
    firstName column: 'fn'
    addresses lazy: false
    addresses column:'Person_ID',joinTable: false
  }
}
```

I already created some Address values in the db so the foreign key **Person_ID** is null.
Now I am trying to update it and set relations to Person with no success.
For some reason, once the object is saved in the db I cannot update the relations.

One of the ways I tried it

```
    Address a1 = new Address();
    a1.setCity("Tester1");
    a1.setStreet("Tester1");

    Person pdb = new Person(firstName: "SupermanB", lastName: "BatmanB");
    pdb.save(flush:true);

    pdb.addToAddresses(a1).save(flush:true);
    pdb.save(flush:true);
```

Does anyone have any idea how can I set relation to an object which already saved in the db?

Thanks

Comment: why did you put `addresses` mapping in 2 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can have `hasMany` without `joinTable` and no back-ref.

The easiest solution would be to change the Address class a bit:

```
class Address {

  static belongsTo = [ person:Person ]
  ...
}
```